# How to hide buttons under layout

Tags: android, button, layout, cover

I have a RelativeLayout as parent layout.In it i've got two buttons and a FrameLayout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="button 1"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="button 2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:background="@color/blue"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>
```

[image: screenshot]

The FrameLayout has both width and height as match_parent but I don't understand why it doesn't cover the buttons.

How can i cover the buttons ?

Comment: Why do you want to hide them? I dont undestand... is to use them without beeing displayed what you want to do?

Comment: Code seems to be fine. Can you clear and rebuild project?

Comment: May be you want the frame layout on buttons? so when layout inflated the buttons will not visible right?

Comment: In my case, I want to verify if my app has stable network connection, and if it doesn't i want to make another layout visible over the main one to notify that the user cannot do any action without network

Comment: and my problem is that the buttons keep staying over the layout,eaven though is match_parent and is the last item in Relative

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the buttons have an attribute called stateListAnimator.

So what you have to do is make another layout file(v21) for lollipop or higher versions and add this in your button xml:

```
android:stateListAnimator="@null"
```

For lower versions of Android it seems to work like this:

```
android:stateListAnimator="@null"
tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute"
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, other solution only adds an extra view to the hierarchy. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Try this code, i have tested it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="button 1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="button 2" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Layouts can hide a layout** .. so to hide a button in the same layout you have to **wrap up the buttons by another layout like this** ..:-

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="button 1"
            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="button 2"

            android:layout_below="@+id/button1"/>
    </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:background="@color/blue"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put your buttons inside `LinearLayout` and it should work.

**eg:-**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="button 1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="button 2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="button 1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="button 2" />

</RelativeLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/blue">

</FrameLayout>
```

Now the code will work.

Answer (score 0):

You added both button in **main root layout**, this will keep always, make another view either be relative or linear and put them both buttons inside this, so this view overlap by framework if it has match parent. Keep other views in Relative layout and make separate `Framelayout`, have look

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="null"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"

        android:text="button 1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"

        android:text="button 2" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:minHeight="500dp">

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope it will help you!!

Answer (score -2):

Add this to your Button tag :

```
<Button
...
android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
```